# Theming the edit form in Drupal 8

Tags: nodes, drupal-8, theming

I am pretty new to Theming in Drupal. So far, I found out that i can create custom templates in my theme, for certain content types.

I am using a **node--content-type.html.twig** for the teasers of a content type.
Then, I use **node--content-type--full.html.twig**, for the full/detail-view of a content-type item.

Now I want to add a template for the edit page of a specific content type.  How do I have to name the node template for this? Something like **node--content-type--edit.html.twig**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to make use of hook_theme() and then pass ID of the form as renderable

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/231192/69482 take a look at this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/308548/69482

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_theme_HOOK_form_alter() for node add/edit.
 */
function theme_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_article_form'){
    $form['#theme'] = ['node_article_edit_form'];
}
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function theme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      'node_article_edit_form' => [
      'template' => 'node_article_edit_form',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'themeName') . '/templates/form',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
}
```